# How to tag viewmodel when using ViewModelLocator?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have multiple instances of a viewmodel:

```
<views:MyView x:Name="view1" mefed:ViewModelLocator.NonSharedViewModel="MyViewModel" />
<views:MyView x:Name="view2" mefed:ViewModelLocator.NonSharedViewModel="MyViewModel" />
```

These two instances should **listen for different messages**. Hence, I need to somehow tag these viewmodel instances. How?

I'm using `MEFedMVVM` and `Prism`. There ought to be a way to let the viewmodel know about some state. E.g.:

```
<views:MyView x:Name="view1" mefed:ViewModelLocator.NonSharedViewModel="MyViewModel">
  <!-- Let the viewmodel know it is of type X -->
</views:MyView>
<views:MyView x:Name="view2" mefed:ViewModelLocator.NonSharedViewModel="MyViewModel">
  <!-- Let the viewmodel know it is of type Y -->
</views:MyView>
```

**How can this be achieved?**

In an ideal world you would use a view's parameterized constructor through XAML, but this is not supported. Another idea is to use different classes for the views, but that will soon bloat the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick Answer and Summary:

As you noticed, what you really want is to parameterize your ViewModel from XAML.  So my instinct is to write an **Attached Behavior** to provide the ability to pass in parameters for your ViewModel.  And more specifically, what comes to mind is that we want a *single* Attached Behavior class that we can specify *both* (a) which ViewModel we want *and* (b) a parameter for that ViewModel.  To satisfy *both* of these desires in a single class while also being as [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible, I think it is easiest to use a "Blend" Behavior, since Blend behaviors are not static classes and thus it seems much easier to be able to use them to pass in both pieces of related information together.

### Explanation:

First a quick disclaimer: I have not used MEFedMVVM or Prism (but I have used other MVVM libraries), so my answer uses a more general approach that I have recently learned to make use of.  Thus, this approach does not rely on any "magic" stuff that Prism may give you when you use things in their "normal" way (i.e., hooking up DataContext automatically, etc.), so let that frame this mindset.

For a good writeup about the differences between "regular" Attached Behaviors and "Blend" Behaviors, I like [**this blog post**](http://briannoyes.net/2012/12/20/AttachedBehaviorsVsAttachedPropertiesVsBlendBehaviors.aspx).  I won't repeat his explanations here, but the key thing I notice is that regular Attached Behaviors seem to just rely on a *single* piece of information (i.e., a single "parameter") in order to do its thing.  Such as (from the blog post):

```
<GridView local:ItemClickNavBehavior.Destination="Home" ...>
```

Now lets put that in terms of your case, and examine how it could work **if you just used *regular* Attached Bahaviors**.  You would write an Attached Behavior class, call it "MyViewModel1Creator" that would:
**(1)** register an attached property called "Type" and
**(2)** include a change callback handler for "Type" (which also gets called when its initially set - see the "HookupBehavior" method in the linked blog post).  In this change callback you would instantiate "ViewModel1" and pass in to it the value of the "Type" Attached Property.  Also in this method you could take care of any other necessities such as setting the DataContext for the View, etc.  You can access the object that the Attached Property is attached to (the the View object in this case) by using the first parameter in the callback handler (the Dependency object param).

Then your Xaml use of the "MyViewModel1Creator" class would look like:

```
<views:MyView x:Name="view1" MyBehaviors:MyViewModel1Creator.Type="X" />
<views:MyView x:Name="view2" MyBehaviors:MyViewModel1Creator.Type="Y" />
```

Although this would work, I see a **disadvantage to this approach** (using *regular* Attached Properties).  To use this approach, you would have to create a separate Attached Behavior class for each ViewModel, meaning that if you had 3 ViewModels ("ViewModel1", "ViewModel2", "ViewModel3") then you would need to write 3 Attached Behavior classes ("ViewModel1Creator", "ViewModel2Creator", "ViewModel3Creator").  Each one would instantiate its respective ViewModel (and expose a "Type" Attached Property as shown above).  Another disadvantage is that it seems to be harder to find a way to add *additional* parameters to pass in.

A slightly alternate approach to the one above, but **equally deficient** in terms of being [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), would be to have a single class (call it "MyViewModelCreator" - without the "1" this time) that houses several Attached Properties with names like "CreateViewModel_1_WithType", "CreateViewModel_2_WithType", "CreateViewModel_3_WithType", etc.  Its usage would look like:

```
<views:MyView x:Name="view1"
              MyBehaviors:MyViewModelCreator.CreateViewModel_1_WithType="X" />
<views:MyView x:Name="view2" 
              MyBehaviors:MyViewModelCreator.CreateViewModel_1_WithType="Y" />
```

Again, these approaches are not very DRY, so we really need to...

### **Now let's consider how it could work if we used a ["Blend" behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726531%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)**:

You would write a class that derives from a typed Behavior - for your views it would probably be `Behavior<UserControl>`, so your class heading might look like:
`public class ViewModelSetupBehavior : Behavior<UserControl>`.  In this class you would: **(1)** register as many Dependency Properties as you like, including a "Type" Dependency Property, and a "ViewModelName" Dependency Property, and **(2)** You will override the `OnAttached()` method, where you will instantiate whichever ViewModel is indicated by the value of the "ViewModelName" Dependency Property, and also pass in to it the value of the "Type" Dependency Property.  Again, this would be the place to also handle any other necessities such as setting the DataContext for the View, etc.  You can access the object that the Behavior is "attached to" (your View in this case) by using the `AssociatedObject` property.

This could let you do this:

```
<views:MyView x:Name="view1">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <MyBehaviors:ViewModelSetupBehavior ViewModelName="ViewModel1" Type="X" SomeOtherParam="bla" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</views:MyView>

<views:MyView x:Name="view2">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <MyBehaviors:ViewModelSetupBehavior ViewModelName="ViewModel1" Type="Y" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</views:MyView>
```

Now notice that we have the ability to use a *single* Behavior class for the creation of *all* of our ViewModels, and we can pass in *several* parameters to dictate how we want the ViewModel to be instantiated.

Comment: Excellent answer! You pin-pointed the exact problems I have encountered so far, and also presented an interesting solution that might work. I'll try it! One more thing; what if `view2` has a `view3` which has another viewmodel? In that case, how could I propagate the behavior of the parent's (`view2`) viewmodel to the child's (`view2`) viewmodel?

Comment: Glad to hear that my answer was useful.  To address your follow up question, I think I need some clarification.  Let me see if I can restate the situation:  `view2` is of type `MyView` and view2's ViewModel's type is `ViewModel1` (as our code above shows).  What type is `view3`?  And what is view3's ViewModel's type?  Finally, what exactly are you wanting to propagate from view2's ViewModel to view3's ViewModel?

Comment: Consider your interaction behavior for `view2`. That implies a viewmodel of type `Y` for `view2`. What if I would like this behavior to be inherited by its child view, `view3`, so that it gets the same type of viewmodel? Maybe I would need an inherited `DependencyProperty` for such a relationship?

Comment: @l33t That's a very interesting question!  In fact, it may warrant a new SO question in order to give it proper attention and input from the community at large.  In essence, it seems like you are asking for an elegant way to utilize some sort of visual-tree-based (or possibly logical-tree-based) property inheritance among your specific Blend behaviors.

Comment: ...(continued) Off hand, I can think of 3 potential ways to solve that problem, though I have not tested these.  I will briefly list these as separate comments b/c it looks like I'm running into character limits for each comment.

Comment: The first way to explore would be built-in WPF property value inheritance abilities. For that approach, you'd need to register your "Type" DP as an Attached DP and set the proper inheritance flags when registering your Attached DP. However, there may be issues with this route that may prevent it from working. For example, I'm seeing some reference from MSDN docs that mention that the parent that holds the value to be inherited must be a part of "some logical tree", and if what my WPF Inspector app is telling me is true, then it appears that Blend behaviors are probably not in the logical tree.

Comment: A second approach that I can think of, while not really using inheritance, and a little less elegant, would be to just use binding.  The child view's ViewModelSetupBehavior's Type property would bind to the parent's ViewModelSetupBehavior's Type property value.  This at least lets you set the Type property in one place.

Comment: The third possibly approach would be to essentially implement your own inheritance structure. It could probably work something like this (again, I have not tested it): In your behavior's OnAttached() method, if you notice that the value of the Type DP is null (this could be your flag to apply inheritance), you traverse the Visual Tree upwards to find an object that has a ViewModelSetupBehavior applied to it, and also check that that Behavior has its Type DP set (otherwise keep traversing upwards). To be continued...

Comment: But you might be asking how do we find an object that has a ViewModelSetupBehavior attached to it? For that we would need the static method Interaction.GetBehaviours(..). For each node visited in your traversal upwards, get the Behaviors of it, check to see if any of them are of type ViewModelSetupBehavior, and if so does it have its Type DP set. If it does, grab that value and apply it to the child ViewModelSetupBehavior's Type DP.  For help with the traversing part, the VisualTreeHelper would probably be your choice.