# How to update a TextBox's value when its Window loses focus?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, user-controls

**A bit of context**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

TextBox controls have a binding option called UpdateSourceTrigger, which is by default set to LostFocus. Howoever, this only works **when the TextBox loses focus within its own Window**. I require the binding to be updated even if the whole owner Window loses its focus.

**Possible solution?**

Now, the Window.Deactivated event seems to do this well.

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow" Deactivated="OnDeactivated">
```

**On to the question**

That being said, how can the TextBox listen on its parent Window's Window.Deactivated event, considering that the TextBox lives under several layers of UserControl objects.

```
Window --> UserControl --> UserControl --> TextBox
```

How can I make the event bubble *down* from the Window to the TextBox? (*ie: have the TextBox listen on the Window.Deactivated event*)

Or maybe there's a better solution out there?

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you need to update the textbox when the window is loosing focus?

Comment: We need the value filled-in to be synced with other clients. If the user clicks elsewhere in the form, it's fine. But if he clicks in another window or app, the value doesn't get synced. Moreover, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is not a viable solution because it would trigger a sync each time the user types a new letter.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I should happen by default.

Comment: It is possible to write your own binding update behavior. [Here's an example that updates source after a pause in typing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6711243/302677) that I have used in the past. Perhaps this could be used to write your own behavior, or maybe it will be suitable for you to use as it is.

Comment: @Rachel I just learned that since WPF 4.5, it's now possible to do built-in. Check out my answer :)

Comment: @asmo Good to know! I haven't worked with WPF too much since 4.0, and I miss it. I'm falling behind on my WPF knowledge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF 4.5 now supports Delay Binding. Combined with PropertyChanged, this means the value will be updated once the user finishes typing, but after a delay of X milliseconds. Pretty rad, right?

```
Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Delay=2000}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a handler for the window deactivated event in your window class and then (within your handler) update your usercontrol (give it a Update method or something) ?

Answer (score 0):

you may use custom behaviour class to achieve this functionality

```
public class CustomBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
//use the override the OnAttached()
}
```